# Getting coordinates of manually drawn points

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a graph as a result of executing `ListPlot[]` function. 
I can manually edit this graph by moving points to a different location 
and also adding new points using the [Drawing Tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html).

How do I get the coordinates of new and changed points from the edited graphics?

Comment: You can probably find useful the `"DisplayFunction"` suboption of `CoordinatesToolOptions` option of `Graphics` which is partially documented in this Wolfram Blog post: "[Get Coordinates: New in 6.0.2](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/03/11/get-coordinates-new-in-602/)" (see also [this MathGroups post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/f6e415f5bf70362d)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach makes every data point a locator that can be moved. New locators can be added and old ones deleted as appropriate. The best fit and variance are updated after every change.

Here's some data of some exponential growth with some errors and a data point missing

```
data = Delete[Table[{t, (1 + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}])Exp[t]}, {t, 0, 2, .2}], 6];
```

A little formatting command:

```
nForm = NumberForm[#, {2, 2}, NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}] &;
```

Finally, here's the code to make the manipulable graphics. [New locators/data points are added](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorAutoCreate.html) using `Alt-Click` (or `Ctrl-Alt-Click` on linux). If you click on the list of points on the left, then a new window is opened containing the points in input form.

```
Manipulate[
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, {None, Temporary, Automatic}],
  nlm = Block[{a,b,t}, NonlinearModelFit[Sort[pts], a Exp[t] + b, {a, b}, t]]; 
  Show[Plot[{Exp[t], nlm[t]}, {t, 0, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, LightGray}, Dotted}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1]], 
   ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue], AxesLabel -> Block[{t,f}, {t, f[t]}]],
  LocatorAutoCreate -> True, Appearance -> Style["\[CircleDot]", Red]],
 {nlm, None}, {{pts, data}, None},
 Dynamic[Pane[EventHandler[
    nForm@Grid[Prepend[pts, {"x", "y"}], Dividers -> {False, 2 -> True}], 
    {"MouseClicked" :> (CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[nlm["Data"], "Output"]}, 
     WindowTitle -> "Data"])}], ImageSize -> {100, 250}, 
   ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable", Scrollbars -> {False, True}]],
 Pane[Dynamic[nForm@Row@{nlm,Row[{"\tvariance = ",nlm["EstimatedVariance"]}]}]],
 ControlPlacement -> {Left, Left, Left, Top}]
```

[image: output from the above]

In the above I've used the locators to correct a couple of outliers and restored the missing data point.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if the following is anything like what you want,but nevertheless:

If I use `ListPlot` as follows:

```
lp1 = Labeled[
   ListPlot[Diagonal@Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 5}], 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}], "lp1"];
```

By double clicking on one of the red points twice to get the selection to the level of the points, I can then move the individual points, e.g., to make the points lie on a curve (rather than a straight line). I now want to extract these points (and say use them in a new `ListPlot`) [see plots below]

If I  click on the bracket of the plot graphic and use "Show Expression" (Command Shift E on a Mac), I can 'see' the coordinates of the modified points which may then be extracted.  For example:

```
expr = Cell[
   BoxData[GraphicsBox[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], PointSize[Large], 
      PointBox[{{0., 1.}, {0.8254488458250212, 
         2.886651181634783}, {1.9301795383300084`, 
         3.925201233010209}, {3.046546974446661, 
         4.597525796319094}, {4., 5.}}]}, 
     AspectRatio -> NCache[GoldenRatio^(-1), 0.6180339887498948], 
     Axes -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
     PlotRangeClipping -> True]], "Input", 
   CellChangeTimes -> {{3.504427833788156*^9, 3.50442786823486*^9}}];
```

Modifying a very useful approach originally suggested by Yaroslav Bulatov, which may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245946/vertexcoordinate-rules-and-vertexlist-from-graphplot-graphic/4250069#4250069)

```
modpoints = Flatten[Cases[expr, PointBox[___], Infinity][[All, 1]], {{2, 1}}]
```

## EDIT

As pointed out by belisarius, it is desirable to be able to extract 'manually' added points (which may be added to the generated plot using 'point' from the Drawing Tools palette). A better way of extracting (after 'Show Expression' ...) is probably the following:

```
modpoints = Cases[Cases[expr, PointBox[___], 
  Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity]
```

Of course, 'Show Expression' is not the only approach.
`InputForm` is another possibility. For example,

```
expr2 = InputForm[ListPlotGraphic]

modpoints = Cases[Cases[expr, Point[___], 
  Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity]
```

where "ListPlotGraphic" is the modified graphic (inserted by 'copy and paste'), will also work.

Example plots

[image]

## Addendum

The above can be automated with a little notebook programming:

```
lp1 = Labeled[
  ListPlot[Diagonal@Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 5}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}],
  Button["Print points",
   With[{nb = ButtonNotebook[]},
    SelectionMove[nb, All, CellContents];
    Print[Cases[NotebookRead[nb], 
       PointBox[{{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}] | 
       PointBox[{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}], Infinity]]]]]
```

Running the above, moving the last two original (red) points and adding a couple of extra points in blue with the drawing tools then pressing the button yields

[image: screenshot]

You can see that there is a single `PointBox` for the original data and a new `PointBox` for each of the added points. Of course, by modifying the above code, you can do more than simply print out the raw point coordinates.

Comment: Unfortunately this requires manual processing. I'd like to use an approach where I can modify coordinates and immediately see the results of such modifications. For instance I would like to run a clustering algorithm for all the points and immediately see which cluster a point belongs to.

Comment: Is there  way to "add" points to the graph, and then get those in the Points list?

Comment: @belisarius That is a good point (no pun intended!).  Points may of course be easily added using the Drawing Tools palette, and I have added a possibly better way of extracting: Cases[Cases[expr, PointBox[___], Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity].  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easy option is to use the "Get Coordinates" menu option. If you right click on the graphic, in the pop-up menu you'll see "Get Coordinates" which allows you to mouse-over a point and see that point's coordinates. Of course this isn't going to be accurate... but the way you're editing the graphic isn't very accurate either.

You could use the `InputForm` (or `FullForm`) function, but I am not sure how well this works...

```
In[1]:= a = ListPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}];
        a // InputForm

Out[2]//InputForm=
Graphics[{{{}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Point[{{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}, {1., 1.}}]}, 
   {}}}, {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

You'll notice that there's a `Point` expression in there.

The third option would be to use `Locator` in some way I guess.

Comment: @Max If you come out with some elegant implementation of Locator[] along with ListPlot[], please post it as an answer. Tnx!

Comment: @belisarius: I just spent way too much time on this question! See the new answer using locators.