# Multigraphs in Mathematica 8

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

I just spent a couple of hours trying to convert [some old code](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ScalarFeynmanDiagramsAndSymanzikPolynomials/) that uses Mathematica 7's `GraphPlot` to use the new Mathematica 8 Graph functions. It seemed sensible since the new graph drawing is much nicer and it has things like `AdjacencyMatrix` and [KirchhoffMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KirchhoffMatrix.html) built in.

**The problem** is that I can not figure out how to get graphs with multiple edges to work in Mma 8.

The Feynman graph that I use as my canonical example is the two-loop vacuum graph

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2}, MultiedgeStyle -> .5, 
          DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

[image: two-loop vacuum sunset graph]

Trying to make the similar graph in Mma 8

```
Graph[{DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[1, 2]}, 
      VertexCoordinates -> {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

yields the error message

```
Graph::supp: Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported. >>
```

How can I construct (and work with) a similar graph using Mathematica 8's `Graph[]` objects?

**Edit:** This problem still exists in Mathematica 9

Comment: The three different graph type objects floating around in Mma8 doesn't help issues... Especially since they don't play together very nicely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I went through a similar process of trying to use `Graph` for everything, and found that it it does not replace `Combinatorica` and `GraphPlot`. The best use for `Graph` is to use it as a container type to store vertices + edges + coordinates.

For example, most of the functions from "Algorithmic Graph Theory" of `Combinatorica` tutorial are not available for new `Graph` objects. When I talked with a WRI developer on `Graph` project, my understanding was providing all of `Combinatorica` functions for `Graph` is not a priority because the design goal is to provide methods that solve tasks in algorithmic agnostic way. For instance, you may have method to find vertex cover and graph coloring for new `Graph` object, but for algorithmic specific tasks like Brelaz coloring and Greedy Vertex Cover, you may always have to defer to `Combinatorica`.

In addition to multi-graphs, some graph layouts are not available for `Graph` objects. You can not fix some vertex coordinates and let automatic layout do the rest. Also, layout of `LayeredGraphPlot` is not available and is sometimes [preferred](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/yaroslav$20bulatov$20graph/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/GBlKD0tiR24/EzXuRorSDKMJ) over `Graph`'s `LayeredDrawing`.

The way to get the best of 3 worlds is to use `Graph` objects as main vehicle for graph storage and make wrappers for `GraphPlot`, `Combinatorica` and `GraphUtilities` functions that accept `Graph` objects

Some use cases:

- You need some algorithm from `Combinatorica` or `GraphUtilities` -- make a wrapper `someAlgorithm` that takes `Graph` object, converts it to list of edges or `Combinatorica` graph (`GraphUtilities'ToCombinatoricaGraph` is helpful), runs the algorithm, converts it back to `Graph` object, taking care to set correct `GraphStyle` and `VertexCoordinates` from the original graph object. Because of conflicts, make sure `Combinatorica` and `GraphUtilities` are not on context path, I [do it](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/281e7fd8870712cb?dmode=source&output=gplain&noredirect) using $Pre
- You need some custom graph plot like [here](http://yaroslavvb.com/blog/blog-lp/cubic-third.png), or the multi-edge graph -- make a wrapper function `someGraphPlot` that accepts `Graph` object, converts it to correct representation, then uses `GraphPlot` or perhaps creates a temporary `Graph` object with custom vertex/edge shapes for the purpose of this one plot. Note that you can attach properties to edges using `SetProperty` so you can store your multigraphs in `Graph` that way.
- You want to use one of `GraphPlot` layouts and store coordinates in `Graph` -- use function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245946/vertexcoordinate-rules-and-vertexlist-from-graphplot-graphic/4250069#4250069) to get vertex coordinates from `GraphPlot` layout, and store them in `Graph` object using `VertexCoordinates`

Here's a [notebook](http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/03/graph-utilities-i-use.html) demonstrating these use cases and a few others

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav. All good advice and interesting comments so I'll give you the "tick".  Unfortunately, it's more than I want to do with this code that I don't use much at the moment. Hopefully by the time I come back to this project WRI will have filled in the gaps (extrapolate their release cycle and we should have v9 or v10 by next year).

Answer (score 9):

The GraphPlot function still works in mma 8.

Multigraphs weren't supported in Combinatorica's functions either. Pretty difficult to implement in an adjecency matrix too. Perhaps working with `EdgeWeight` may work in calculations?

For drawing multiple links I can imagine that 'EdgeShapeFunction' may help you.

```
ef[pts_List, e_] :=
 Block[{g1 = 
    Insert[pts, (pts[[1]] + pts[[-1]])/
      2 + ({x, y}/5 /. 
        Solve[{Norm[{x, y}] == 1, (pts[[1]] - pts[[-1]]).{x, y} == 
            0}, {x, y}][[1]]), Round[(Length[pts] + 1)/2]],
   g2 = Insert[
     pts, (pts[[1]] + pts[[-1]])/
      2 + (-{x, y}/5 /. 
        Solve[{Norm[{x, y}] == 1, (pts[[1]] - pts[[-1]]).{x, y} == 
            0}, {x, y}][[1]]), Round[(Length[pts] + 1)/2]]}, {Arrow[
    BSplineCurve[g1]], Arrow[BSplineCurve[g2]], Arrow[pts]}]

Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1},
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ef]
```

[image]

or for selected edges  :

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1},
  EdgeShapeFunction -> {3 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> ef}]
```

[image]

The function ef can be easily parametrized for the number of edges to draw.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd. I can imagine hooking up such a `EdgeShapeFunction` to automatically check for integer weighted edges - so your `eft` is quite useful useful code. But I've completely lost enthusiasm for updating my code right now... I'll come back to it later, or wait for WRI to clean up their `Graph` code.

Answer (score 2):

These are not yet supported, I guess:

```
In[201]:= AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 3}, {0, 0}}]

During evaluation of In[201]:= Graph::supp: Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported. >>

Out[201]= AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 3}, {0, 0}}]
```

although this might not be the answer you hope to get.

Comment: I find it strange that this type of input doesn't work - since there is support for weighted adjacency matrices.