# product of three matrices ends up an odd block matrix?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, matrix-multiplication

In the following bit of mathematica code

```
a1 = {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}
a2 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
a3 = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}
c = I*a1*a2 // MatrixForm
d = c*a3 // MatrixForm
```

The display of d shows up as a two by two matrix, where the 1,1 and 2,2 elements are themselves 2x2 matrixes, whereas I expect it to be a plain old 2x2 matrix of scalars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use () to protect expression from MatrixFrom which is a wrapper.
use '.' for matrix multiplication. Not '*'

a1 = {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}
a2 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
a3 = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}
(c = I a1.a2) // MatrixForm
(d = c.a3) // MatrixForm
```

This is the output I get for d:

```
(1  0
 0  1)
```

Comment: You beat me by "---" that much! (Also, there is [no need to sign your posts in SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), I've removed your signature.)

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the classic gotchas in Mathematica.

The `MatrixForm` display wrapper has a higher precedence than the `Set` operator (`=`).

Assuming (based on your tag selection) that you meant to use matrix multiplication `Dot` (`.`) instead of Times (`*`), I would write

```
a1 = {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}
a2 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
a3 = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}
(c = I a1.a2) // MatrixForm
(d = c.a3) // MatrixForm
```

which returns for `c` and `d` respectively:

```
(1  0
 0  -1)

(1  0
 0  1)
```

---

Edit:
I forgot to mention if you do enter

```
c = I a1.a2 // MatrixForm
```

Then a quick look at the `FullForm` of `c` will show you what the problem is:

```
In[6]:= FullForm[c]
Out[6]//FullForm= MatrixForm[List[List[1,0],List[0,-1]]]
```

You can see that it has the `Head[c] == MatrixForm` and so it won't play nice with the other matrices.

Comment: @Peeter The `FullForm` importance can't be emphasized enough. You will find yourself using it whenever you need to understand any unexpected result

Comment: @belisarius: Except in the version 8 `Graph` objects. Where `FullForm` acts more like python's `__repr__(self)` method, it gives you an output which will let you recreate the object. :(

Comment: @Simon Yeah. If WRI is going that way, many tasks will become tough :)

Comment: "output which will let you recreate the object" -- I seem to recall WReach (I think) writing even that is not true, as it can/does give output that is not valid input.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: You mean [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301833/new-graph-in-mathematica-8-0/4356488#4356488)? Anyway, this probably isn't the right place to have a [whinge about the new `Graph` objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485405/multigraphs-in-mathematica-8)!

Comment: Yes, but I will be glad to delete my comment.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It corrects/clarifies my statement, so I have no problem with it.