# mixed graph and mathematica 9

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica, social-networking

I want to make network analysis with my data.

So I use function graph but Mathematica say "Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported"

I have 1984 connections with some redondance: A-->A, A-->A

Have you some idea to solve this problem in using graph?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't thing that v9 has changed much of the thinking displayed in this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485405/multigraphs-in-mathematica-8

Comment: how I can adjust EdgeShapeFunction for my example with 1984 connections?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't see how adjusting your EdgeShapeFunction has a bearing on Mathematica's unwillingness to draw mixed and multi-graphs.  You'll have to provide much more detail about what you are doing and what you want to do if you want any useful help.